# dialogClass not applying the given style class

Tags: jquery, css

Am using 2 `Jquery Dialog` box in my xhtml page. There are 2 links and when a user clicks on those links each link will render a different `Dialog` box. Different `Dialog` box in the sense look and feel are different. Since both are referring to jquery-ui-rev.css whatever CSS changes are done in that `.css` file, it is getting applied to both the `Dialog` box.

[image: Image from Chrome web developer is attached for reference]

So, I tried with `dialogClass` . I applied `dialogClass` for one of the `Dialog` box and left the other as it is.

And I came up with below code and deployed it.

```
$j("#dialog").dialog({
    dialogClass: 'ui-dialog',
      ....

<head>
<style type="text/css">
 .ui-dialog
{
padding: none;
overflow: hidden;
position: absolute;
width: 100px;
left: 100px;
top: 100px;
}
</style>
</head>
```

But, `ui-dialog` class I have written here is not overriding the standard `ui-dialog` class of `jquery-ui-rev.css`. Then, I also tried with a different name for `ui-dialog`. i.e., I renamed `ui-dialog` with `my-dialog`. Even then `my-dialog` is not getting applied for `Dialog` box. It still takes from standard CSS class of `ui-dialog`.

Then, I also tried with below code

```
$j("#dialog").addClass('my-dialog').dialog({
```

This also couldn't override the standard `ui-dialog` class.

PS Note : I have renamed `jquery-ui-rev.css` to `jquery-ui-curretpacks.css`. `jquery-ui-currentpacks.css` contains exact contents of `jquery-ui-rev.css`

**@Dipaks** I have tried the solution as you have mentioned. Code is as below,

```
$('.ui-dialog').addClass('new-ui-dialog');
$j("#dialog").dialog({
    dialogClass: 'new-ui-dialog',
....
```

But, as I have attached in the new image, it can be seen that though ui-dialog is getting replaced by new-ui-dialog, but css properties are still taken from ui-dialog.

I also gave a try without dialogClass like below,
    $j("#dialog").dialog({
    .....

```
<style type="text/css">
.new-ui-dialog
{
 //my new css
}
</style>
```

[image]

Am attaching 3rd image here. In this SS, new-ui-dialog attributes are overridden still. [image: Image3]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.ui-dialog` is adding **inline** css for the element. If you want to override these styles do this -

```
$('.ui-dialog').addClass('new-ui-dialog');
```

CSS -

```
.new-ui-dialog { color: red !important; }
```

Comment: I have mentioned my observation in my question. Kindly refer the results. I tried as you suggested. Still it didnt work!

Comment: I have attached 3rd image. It can be seen that new-ui-dialog attributes are overridden by element.style

Comment: It works ! Sorry. My bad. There was a typo mistake in !important