# Maximum number of dialogClass in Jquery Dialog box

Tags: jquery, css

Am using `Jquery Dialog` box in my xhtml page. Since there are 2 `Jquery Dialog` box and look & feel of each box was different from the other, I had to use `addClass` attribute and this has been discussed in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12956504/dialogclass-not-applying-the-given-style-class/12956620#comment17583423_12956620). Now I have to override many classes like `ui-dialog, ui-corner-all, ui-widget-header` etc. So, I went on adding the classes using `addClass`. Code is below,

```
$('.ui-widget-content').addClass('new-ui-widget-content');
$('.ui-widget').addClass('new-ui-widget');
$('.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar').addClass('new-ui-dialog new-ui-dialog-titlebar');
$('.ui-widget-header').addClass('new-ui-widget-header');
 $('.ui-helper-clearfix').addClass('new-ui-helper-clearfix');
 ....

$j("#dialog").dialog({
dialogClass: 'new-ui-widget-content',
dialogClass: 'new-ui-widget',
dialogClass: 'new-ui-dialog new-ui-dialog-titlebar',
dialogClass: 'new-ui-widget-header',
dialogClass: 'new-ui-helper-clearfix',
....
```

But, I noticed that only 1 of the classes is getting overridden. I mean to say, though I have overridden many classes, only `new-ui-widget-content` is getting overridden(which is placed first).

I also tried in below way. But it gives syntax error.

```
    $j("#dialog").dialog({
        dialogClass: 'new-ui-widget-content','new-ui-widget',......
```

Can multiple classes be overridden by `addClass`?

If so, how it can be done?

Comment: "I have to override many classes" Why? Can't you just remove the default plugin stylesheets or edit them to your needs? Also by adding additional classes you are not overriding them, but adding another class. You could also try to remove the original classes: `.removeClass()`.

Comment: @feeela  I have imported `jquery-ui-rev.css` I have edited this CSS as per Dialog box1. This is also getting applied to Dialog box2. If I edit this CSS as per Dialog box2, it will affect Dialog box1. So, for Dialog box2 I need to override attributes of box1. Hope am clear. I ll check out `removeClass`.

Comment: No, there is `toggleClass( 'test1' )`, but that function would add 'test1' if it's not present and remove it if existing. To replace a class you have to call both, the add- and remove-functions: `$( '.ui-widget' ).removeClass( 'ui-widget' ).addClass( 'new-ui-widget' );`

Comment: @feeela I tried `removeClass` and `addClass` both. Even then only the first attribute that am placing inside `$j("#dialog").dialog({` code, that is getting overridden and not others :(

Comment: I still don't get, why at all are you trying to change some CSS classes…

Comment: @feeela Ok. Let me try to explain. I have one xhtml page. In this page there are 2 links for the user. Both the links open a Jquery Dialog box. But, both look different. For eg., Dialog box1 has more width than Dialog box2. I have imported `jquery-ui-rev.css` class file in my xhtml page. There is `width` attribute in `ui-dialog`. Whatever `width` I have given for Box1 in `jquery-ui-rev.css`, is also getting applied for Box2. This is the reason why am trying to override `ui-dialog` for Box2. For Box1, I have not overridded. Whatever is mentioned in `jquery-ui-rev.css`, its taking from there.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18465/discussion-between-vikas-v-and-feeela)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really should overwrite unwanted styling from CSS, not by exchanging multiple CSS classes via JavaScript. All you need is some identifier for the second dialog. If `#dialog` is the first one, I guess the second one is named something along `#dialog2`.

Add a second stylesheet file to the HTML page or append to the original `jquery-ui-rev.css`.
You additional styles should reflect the slectors in question, but preceded by a `#dialog2`, which increases the specificity and sets special formattings for any such classes inside a wrapper named `#dialog2`.

As I couldn't find a `jquery-ui-rev.css`, I'll give you an example based on [the `jquery.ui.dialog.css`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/themes/base/jquery.ui.dialog.css).

If you want to overwrite some specific property from the selector `.ui-dialog`, which is in original:

```
.ui-dialog { position: absolute; padding: .2em; width: 300px; overflow: hidden; }
```

…you could do so by setting up another selector, while only re-specifying the appropriate properties:

```
#dialog2 .ui-dialog {
    width: 500px;
}
```

Comment: `#dialog1 .ui-dialog` is not getting overwritten by `#dialog2 .ui-dialog`. If it could have been overwritten like this, what is the use of `addClass`, `removeClass` ... Am not questioning your above answer. Am asking this to myself and seeking your help in understanding the same

Comment: @VikasV "`#dialog1 .ui-dialog` is not getting overwritten by `#dialog2 .ui-dialog`" WHY? Utilize some browsers code inspector and check in which order the CSS declaration appear…